# IOS Emulator unable to access services

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to make a application with a private api. it perfectly work on ionic serve and android build apk. but in ios simulator and ios build in iPhone, it did not access the api service. how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed cordova-plugin-ionic-webview and everything works well.